# How to run SoLiD behind traefik

Tags: traefik, solid

I'd like to run [node-solid-server](https://github.com/solid/node-solid-server) as docker, configured by docker-compose, behind træfik. Because solid uses [webid-tls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebID#WebID-TLS) all encrypted requests need to be bypassed through the frontend proxy.

How to bypass all TLS to the solid docker?

Comment: Please, show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I actually gave up and run it now in a lxd container. træfik seems not to support ssl passthrough which is required for node-solid-server.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347059/ssl-passthrough-with-traefik